# I can't get an error response node.js return in angular

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular

I want to get an error response message sent by node with angular, but I can not do that.

Node.js:

```
res.status(401).send({ "ERROR": "001", "message": "this is error" });
```

Angular:

```
public get(body) {
    return this.httpClient.post(`${this.API_URL}~`, body).catch(this.handleError);;
  }

  private handleError(error: any) {
    console.log(error);
    return Observable.throw(error);
  }
```

console in chorme

```
Http failure response for http://localhost:8000/~: 401 Unauthorized
```

response in chome

```
{"ERROR": "001", "message": "this is error"}
```

Although I can confirm it on the chrome network , I can not use the error message in angular because the output in console.log is `'Http failure response for http: // localhost: 8000 / ~: 401 Unauthorized'`

Answer (score 3):

When it comes to error handling in Angular, the best practice would be to handle it through pipeable operations using RxJS operators.

You can do so by using the [catchError](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/error_handling/catch.html) operator.

```
import { catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';
.
.

public get(body) {
  return this.httpClient.post(`${this.API_URL}~`, body)
    .pipe(
      map(...),
      catchError(error => {
        // to get error response object
        console.log(error);
        // handle the rest of the error here
      })
    );
}
```

To access the error code, you can use `error.status`.

To access the error message, you can use `error.message`.

Comment: I'm sorry. I wrote the wrong intercept method of the ErrorInterceptor class I wrote. The error was able to be acquired with angular even with existing code

Comment: @KATUO I guess you must have solved your problem then? Glad to hear that :)